# Link Microsoft Visual Studio DLL to a WDK LIB

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7, wdk

Is it possible to link a LIB file generated from the WDK to a DLL being built in Visual Studio? The versions would be VS2010 and WDK 7.1.

I'm experiencing linker errors and was wondering if this was even possible.

Comment: Thanks for not adding a comment and down voting me. This should be a place to learn and share knowledge. This is a pretty poor way of doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can link a WDK LIB into a MSVS DLL. My problem was that I was not marking exported functions with the `extern "C"` qualifier.